# How to dynamically pass the default_value in the PipelineParameter in Azure ML ADF interface?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to pass the value dynamically for default_value in the pipeline parameter to avoid the duplication of the entire pipeline for each parameter value.

[image: A snapshot of the pipeline python script]

Any immediate help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You could make a dict with `{"param_name": "default_value"}` elements and then use `for` loop to set pipeline parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below code block and replace this with your existing code block and try to re-execute

```
response = requests.post(published_pipeline1.endpoint,
                         headers=aad_token,
                         json={"ExperimentName": "My_Pipeline",
                               "ParameterAssignments": {"pipeline_arg": 20}}
```

Kindly refer the official documentations for further **reference**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-pipelines#run-a-published-pipeline